# Java: se puede meter dos arrays unidimensionales en un array bidemensional

Tags: java

Me piden un programa, este debe leer las edades de los alumnos de dos clases por separado, entonces he creado dos arrays, classe A, classe B, lee una clase y luego las edades de la otra classe, pero el programa pide que cuando esten introducidas se comparen las edades y si la clase B tiene alumnos de igual edad o menor que la classe A hay que mostrar un mensage por pantalla.

Se me ocurre meter los datos de los dos arrays classe A, classe B en un array bidimensional y utilizar el bucle de la burbuja para comparar las edades con un contador que me ayude a ver si la clase B tendra alumnos <= a classe A, pero no se si se puede de algun modo meter dos arrays unidimensional en array bidimensional.

Dejo el codigo hasta donde he llegado.

```
public class ProgramaDeClasesEac {

int[] classesA = null;
int[] classesB = null;
int[][] classesAiB = null;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProgramaDeClasesEac programa = new ProgramaDeClasesEac();
    programa.inici();

}

private void inici() {
    intro();
    entraMida();
    entraPosicions();
    imprimeixPosicions();
}

private void intro() {
    System.out.println("Aquest programa et demana que entris la mida de dos clases A y B.\n"
            + "Despres et demanara que entris les edats dels alumnes. \n"
            + "Una vegada estiguien entrades comparara les dues clases y retornara si la classe"
            + "<B> es mes gran que la classe <A>.");
}

private void entraMida() {
    System.out.println("Digam la mida que tenen les clases A i B:");
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int mida = scan.nextInt();
        classesA = new int[mida];
        classesB = new int[mida];
        classesAiB = new int[mida][mida];
    } else {
        scan.next();
        System.out.print("Aquest valor no és correcte. ");
    }
}

private void entraPosicions() {

    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("introdueix la posicio: " + (i + 1) + " de la clase A:");
        classesA[i] = scan.nextInt();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < classesB.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("introdueix la posicio: " + (i + 1) + " de la clase B:");
        classesB[i] = scan.nextInt();

    }

}

private void imprimeixPosicions() {
    System.out.print("Collectio 1: \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(classesA[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.print("Collectio 2: \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < classesB.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(classesB[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("  ");
}

private void Compara() {

    for (int i = 0; i < classesAiB.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < classesAiB.length; j++) {

        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de concepto aquí. Ya que si tienes 10 alumnos en la clase A y 9 en la B, al crear el array bidimensional tendras un array de 10x9... es decir 90 "espacios" no un array de dos filas de 10 y 9 como creo que intentas hacer. Creo que para el simple hecho de comparar las clases no necesitas mas que un for dentro de otro y recorrer el array `claseB` por cada posicion del `claseA`, por ejemplo:

```
private void Compara() {

    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < classesB.length; j++) {
            // TO-DO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes razon, es una simple comparacion recorriendo los dos array, lo he hecho asi:  private void Compara() {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {
            
            for ( int j=0; j<classesB.length; j++){
            if (classesB[i] <= classesA[j]) {
                contador++;
            }
            }
        }
        
        if (contador >= 1) {
            System.out.println("No se cumple que la clase B tiene los alumnos mayores de edad de la A");
      .....else

Comment: Perfecto @Carlos, marcaste la otra respuesta como correcta por eso, para futuros usuarios mejor marques la mía si te ayudó. Un saludo!

Comment: Disculpas queria marcar las dos como buenas, ahora he hecho click en la tuya. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer poder ayudar

Comment: Creo que se ha vuelto a marcar la otra respuesta como correcta, solo puedes marcar una de las dos como la que mas te ha ayudado.

Comment: Hola Josep la que mas me ha ayudado es la tuya, pues habia que enteder que habia un error de concepto, he marcado nuevamente la tuya con el tick verde, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, sería de la siguiente forma

`classesAiB = {classesA, classesB};`

No obstante si lo que tienes es que contar el numero de alumnos menores, creo que no vas bien encaminado. Tienes la opción de Josep o incluso puedes ordenar los dos arrays con Arrays.sort de forma ascendente y buscar hasta donde se incumple la condición.

Comment: Gracias, tenia razon Josep, no era el tema... pero me anoto la forma por si me vuelve a salir.